# Adding data for dates between updates?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm doing some research on some warehouse data, where the qty are only updated infrequently, and we want to change this to a series that has a value for each product_id, by day.
A simplified table of what it is:

| product_id | dateUpdated | qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-07-01 | 1 |
| 2 | 2021-07-02 | 2 |
| 1 | 2021-08-15 | 5 |
| 1 | 2021-08-21 | 3 |

```
library(tidyverse)
mydata <- data.frame(product_id = c(1, 2, 1, 1), dateUpdated = c(as.Date('2021-07-01'), as.Date('2021-07-02'), as.Date('2021-08-15'), as.Date('2021-08-21')), qty = c(1, 2, 5, 3))
```

Assuming that the product doesn't exist until it's first updated, I'm kind of at lost for what methods I should be using to even begin this right now. My goal would be:

| product_id | dateUpdated | qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-07-01 | 1 |
| 1 | 2021-07-02 | 1 |
| 2 | 2021-07-02 | 2 |
| 1 | 2021-07-03 | 1 |
| 2 | 2021-07-03 | 2 |

..until the last day of August, updating only when the qty was updated.

I'm thinking about using for loops in base R, but is there a great way to do this using dyplr and some other libraries potentially?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

mydata %>%
  group_by(product_id) %>%
  complete(dateUpdated = seq(min(dateUpdated), as.Date("2021-08-31"), by = "day")) %>%
  fill(qty, .direction = "down") %>%
  ungroup()
```

Comment: sweet thank you!